# openpyxl TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, typeerror, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl, os 

cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Hello.xlsx')
print (type(wb))

sheetNames = wb.sheetnames
print(sheetNames[1])

sheet0 = sheetNames[0]
print (sheet0['A1']) <--TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I have tried to use .value at the end too. The cell contains the number 55 in it. I am new to python so please help. Also if anyone has a good place for resources on excel and python that would be helpful. openpyxl seems to be the newest one so I am trying to use this but the documentation is poor.

Comment: I have programmed in Matlab for sometime and am trying to make the transition to python

Comment: `sheet0` is a string, you have to use integers to access its character elements. e.g. `sheet0[3]`

Comment: `wb.sheetnames` returns a list of strings, you probably want another method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sheetname0 is the name for the first sheet. So what you're doing when you run `sheetname0['A1']` is you're trying to access element `A1` of a string - which doesn't make sense. If you wish you access the cell `A1` of that sheet you must first access that sheet object.

`ws = wb[sheetNames[0]]`

Now that you have the sheet you can access the cell:

`print(ws['A1'])`

Also a general tip for Python considering you said you're new to it it's generally recommended you use `snake_case` for variable names.

Comment: Thank  you for  your reply and suggestion on snake_case.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` as `sheet0` is in fact a string (not the worksheet itself).

`wb.sheetnames` gives you a list of all of the worksheet names, e.g.

```
['Sheet 1', 'Sheet 2', 'Sheet 3']
```

So `sheetNames[0]` would give you the first sheet name `Sheet 1` as a string.

To work with the data you need to first open the worksheet using the required sheet name.

You can also use `wb.active` to get the first worksheet object i.e. `Sheet 1` to avoid the need to use `wb.sheetnames`:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Hello.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
print(ws['A1'].value)
```

To get the corresponding worksheet object you would use:

```
ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]
print(ws['A1'].value)
```